# android - reset progress bar on back pressed button

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, android-progressbar

Since android 5.0 api 22 I have a problem on my app.

I have an activity called "time progress" (its not my main activity). On that activity I have a chronometer with a circular progress bar, so the time goes from 15 to 0 and progress bar is filling up.

When I click on back button to go to the main menu and then I go again to the "time progress" my progress bar its not empty (has some value, like 15 or 3 or 8, random values) and I want the progress bar empty.

I tried onstop(); flag_activity_no_history, flag_activity_new_task, flag_activity_clear_top, set progressbar to 0 but nothing works.

Here is my code

```
int j = 0;
public void timetest() {
    CountDownTimer countdown = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
    TextView timetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetext);
    ProgressBar progresstime = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progresstime);
       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          timetext.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
          j = j + 1;
          progresstime.setProgress(j);
      }
    }
      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
         playtime.setText("Time's up");
     }
   }.start();
  }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backmainmenu = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(backmainmenu);
  }
```

Should start always like this: [Image1](http://postimg.org/image/62ledzapp)

And not like this: [Image2](http://postimg.org/image/6te4jrd31)

Maybe I applied those functions in the wrong way :/ .

Any help please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't place some code in your onCreate() method to set the progress to 0 like:

```
progresstime.setProgress(0);
```

EDIT:

If set progressBar to 0 dont work. You can create a new instance of progressBar

Comment: i tried to setprogress(0) but didnt work, should be work i dont know why
also i tried now to create a new instance but i think i am doing wrong, can you explain me a little about that ?

Comment: Put some code form onCreate() method to see if there's something wrong. I'm not sure but I think that if new Instance of your activity "time progress" is created then progressbar should not have any start value. Check in your manifest if you have any flag that could be causing this. Like activity single_top or something... Good Luck!